# How can I filter posts by user profiles with a certain field value? - Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I am creating a blog application using Django and I would like to filter the blog posts using user profiles with a certain field value. For example, let's say that there is a field for professions in the profile model of the users, I would like to filter all the posts posted by doctors. Is this possible and if so, how would I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a foreign key from Blog to User, then do this:

```
Blog.objects.filter(user__profile='doctor')
```